# Why does my code not produce the expected result? It prints more than what I want

Tags: javascript

Here is my code and I expect it prints out a number, instead, it prints out a number plus all my codes.

```js
function Employee(salaryJan, salaryFeb, salaryMar){
    this.salaryJan = salaryJan;
    this.salaryFeb = salaryFeb;
    this.salaryMar = salaryMar;
}

var dennis = new Employee(6575, 7631, 8000);

Employee.prototype.sumAll = function(){
    var sum = 0;
    for (salary in this){
        sum += this[salary];
    }
    console.log(sum);
};

dennis.sumAll();
```

Currently my codes prints out:

```js
22206function (){
    var sum = 0;
    for (salary in this){
        sum += this[salary];
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

I just want `22206`, and I have no idea why it also prints out some code.

I have a JSFiddle fiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/LZeQr/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem:

```
for (salary in this)
```

This will loop through all properties of `this`. Let's see those properties:

```
this.salaryJan
this.salaryFeb
this.salaryMar
Employee.prototype.sumAll
```

You've got 4 properties which is what you see getting printed to the console.

You should use the [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) method:

```
for (prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) 
        sum += this[prop];
    }
}
```

And here's a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SnQcd/1/).

Comment: Hi Darin, but if my codes is this, your method does not work. http://jsfiddle.net/dennisboys/LZeQr/2/, how can I solve this?

Comment: In this case you need to test whether the property is not a function: http://jsfiddle.net/LZeQr/3/